# How does $10^{100}$ = $2^{\frac{100}{\log2}}$?

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

[Googol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Googol) is equal to $10^{100}$. To determine the number of bits that it needs to represented in binary, we need to rewrite Googol with a base of $2$. This is the correct answer:

$$10^{100} = 2^{\frac{100}{\log2}}$$

Can someone show me the process work for getting to that answer?

Edit: Please don't use the answer in your solution. Simply go from $10^{100}$ to the answer, assuming you had never known the answer in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We want to solve for $x$, where:
$$
10^{100} = 2^x
$$

To this end, we take the common logarithm of both sides to obtain:
\begin{align*}
\log(10^{100}) &= \log(2^x) \\
100\log(10) &= x\log(2) \\
100 &= x\log(2) \\
x &= \frac{100}{\log 2}
\end{align*}

Hence, we conclude that:
$$
10^{100} = 2^{\frac{100}{\log 2}}
$$

Comment: I didn't think to try and solve for a variable where it was equal to $2^{x}$. This is what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! =]